# How to transform Observable result in piping process

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-observable

since there is no API response fits the size of wanted data interface, we need to transform HttpResponse to match it  with our type defined method

got an error saying that Result does not exist on type 'Tag[]'

```
 Interface Tag{
     title:string;
    }

searchTag(term:string):Observable<Tag[]>{
  const url = 'api/tags'    
  return this.http.get<Tag[]>(url).pipe(map(tags=>tags.Result)) <<-error here 
}
```

Noting that I am mapping Observable response into Result object since GET 'api/tags' response is like below, that's why I am supposed to map the tags above in the pipe to **Result**.

```
 {
    "Operation": "GET/allTags",
    "Count": 2,
    "Result": [{"title": "tsadg"}]
}
```

Comment: Your response *isn't* shaped like a `Tag[]`; your type hint needs to match the actual response to be any use at all. At the very least: `{ Result: Tag[] }`.

Comment: try that `this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(map(resp=>resp.Result as Tag[])) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe advised!, you taught TS that http client instance will  get back the response with a Tag shape, where Result is undefined there! though you have to reshape your http response hint type to be like

```
<{Result:Tag[]}>
```

now TS won't object over accessing result since it's a part of it's shape